# Stackblitz: change compilation target to es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component, stackblitz

Stackblitz compiles the code to es5 (or es3).

The problem is that web components need the class notation in order to work.

In the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wyiwug?file=index.html) here, I'm trying to use the 3rd party @material web components.

Is there any way to tell stackblitz not to compile certain libraries or give it a target compilation to es6 (preferably es2020)?

Comment: ES6 and ES2020 are two very different targets. ES6 is equivalent to ES2015, a full five years before ES2020 was published.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. The main point is - I need classes in order for my web components to work with stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `custom-elements-es5-adapter` to your imports or html (depending on your needs).

Docs for using [custom-elements-es5-adapter.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs)

```
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lkfejz?file=index.js)

---

**Further examples:**

using `script src` in html: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webcomponent-custom-element?file=index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  </head>
```

using import `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js` : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kt759o?file=index.js)

```
// These imports must be first.
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js';
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';
// All other top-level imports should be specified here so that (a) they follow
// the polyfills and adapter and (b) so that stackblitz will convert their
// module specifiers.
import '@polymer/iron-selector/iron-selector.js';
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-woikq4?file=index.js